# Maintenance in OOP

Tags: oop

What is maintenance in the context of object oriented programming?I thought it was writing a readable code, refactoring and other things. But I got it wrong in an exam. Please briefly explain.

Comment: is this an email to your professor?

Comment: "Maintenance" is not an object-oriented concept...

Comment: @MattBusche no. I already done the exam. But I wasn't given marks for that. I asked here to clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what was the actual question and the answer you gave? depending on the context could be why no points were given.

maintenance of software is a general term. such as is the fixing of bugs, improving the code quality, etc. techniques include refactoring.

However code is written for maintainability, which covers a number of things to look for

- Strong cohesion and low coupling
- Encapsulation
- Use of design patterns
- Code metrics - cyclomatic complexity (not just OO)

Have a look at the SOLID principals and Command–query separation

if the question was about how to achieve maintainable code in OO, then I would expect the above

Answer (score 0):

> maintenance in the context of object oriented programming

A well structured code where OO concepts are properly applied is easier to be maintained by ourselves and those "inheriting" our project as time passes.

This is the only answer I can give that could make sense of your sentence